# Parsing xml using Boost c++ for nested tags

Tags: c++, xml, boost, boost-propertytree

I am trying to parse an xml file using boost which is of the following structure:

```
<root> 
  <chocos> 
    <choco>
      <color>1</color>
    <companies>
      <comapany>10</company>
      <comapany>11</company>
    </companies>
  </choco>
  <choco>
    <color>2</color>
    <companies>
      <comapany>12</company>
      <comapany>13</company>
    </companies>
   </choco>
 </chocos>
</root>
```

I need to store it in the following class:

```
class root_info
{
   public:
      //some members
      std::vector<choco_info> chocos;
}

class choco_info
{
   int color;
   int companies[100];
}
```

I have written the following code, but it shows error :

> No such node (companies)Failed to read xml file>

Code:

```
  for(const auto& v : pt.get_child("root.chocos"))
  {
     choco_info choco;
     if(v.first == "choco")
     {
        choco.color = v.second.get<unsigned>("color");
        int i = 0;
        for(const auto& v2 : pt.get_child("companies"))
        {
           if( v2.first == "company")
           {
              choco.company[i] = v2.second.get<unsigned>("company");
              i++;
           }
        }
     }
     root.chocos.push_back(choco);
  }
```

The **xml cannot be changed** as it has been given to me. The main problem lies in how to **iterate** through "chocos" as well as "companies"

Comment: `pt.get_child("companies")` looks suspicious to me. Shouldn't it be `v.second.get_child("companies")`

Comment: You even didn't mention what boost library you're using.

Comment: @drescherjm : I made that change. It is now showing the same error for the next node i.e. "company". Is that the wrong way to access that node?

Comment: @drescherjm : Got it! I needed to write v2.first == "companies" .

Answer (score 0):

Structuring your code helps a lot in keeping the complexity down:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4261d685bae8520b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

std::string const sample = R"(<root> 
  <chocos> 
    <choco>
      <color>1</color>
    <companies>
      <comapany>10</company>
      <comapany>11</company>
    </companies>
  </choco>
  <choco>
    <color>2</color>
    <companies>
      <comapany>12</company>
      <comapany>13</company>
    </companies>
   </choco>
 </chocos>
</root>)";

using boost::property_tree::ptree;

using companies_t = std::vector<int>;

struct choco_info {
   int color;
   companies_t companies;
};

using chocos_t = std::vector<choco_info>;

struct root_info {
    //some members
    chocos_t chocos;
};

bool read_companies(ptree const& pt, companies_t& into) {
    for (auto& [name,child] : pt)
        if (name == "comapany") // FIXME
            into.push_back(child.get_value<int>());
        else 
            return false;
    return true;
}
bool read_chocos(ptree const& pt, chocos_t& into) {
    for (auto& [name,child] : pt) {
        if (name == "choco") {
            choco_info ci;
            ci.color = child.get("color", -1);
            if (!read_companies(child.get_child("companies"), ci.companies))
                return false;

            into.push_back(std::move(ci));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    ptree pt;
    {
        std::istringstream iss(sample);
        read_xml(iss, pt);
    }

    root_info result;

    bool ok = true;
    try {
        ok = read_chocos(pt.get_child("root.chocos"), result.chocos);
    } catch(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        ok = false;
    }

    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "Parsed:\n";
        for (auto& choco : result.chocos) {
            std::cout << " - color " << choco.color << "\n";
            for (int company : choco.companies)
                std::cout << "   * company " << company << "\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Error in input\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed:
 - color 1
   * company 10
   * company 11
 - color 2
   * company 12
   * company 13
```

Comment: I am compilation error :

In function ‘bool read_companies(const ptree&, companies_t&)’:
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
     for (auto& [name,child] : pt)
expected ‘;’ before ‘:’ token
And similarly for read_chocos function. 

Also showing "‘name’ was not declared in this scope" and "‘child’ was not declared in this scope"

Comment: I have checked and I am not missing any semicolons or other needed tokens anywhere.